# convert array to arraylist?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

How do I convert in AIR 2 for List component to display items?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var a:Array = ['some','values','in','an','array'];
var aList:ArrayList = new ArrayList(a);
```

[documentation for ArrayList constructor](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ArrayList.html#ArrayList())

Comment: Oh great, actionscript really easy!